# Jackson ObjectMapper Unexpected character - JSON is valid

Tags: java, json, file, jackson

I am trying to write/read a simple class to a file using Jackson and I can't get read the file after I create it. I get

> org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('.' (code 46)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
>    at [Source: java.io.StringReader@f2dec59; line: 1, column: 2]

My object is pretty straightforward; it's basically just a container for a HashMap. Here is the resulting JSON file that I checked out with JSONLint:

```
{
"quaternions": {
    "10": {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "z": 0,
        "w": 1,
        "identity": true
    },
    "11": {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "z": 0,
        "w": 1,
        "identity": true
    },
    "12": {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "z": 0,
        "w": 0,
        "identity": false
    }
}
}
```

The code I am using to read the file is as follows:

```
TypeReference<ZeroQuaternions> typeRef;
typeRef = new TypeReference<ZeroQuaternions>() {};
ZeroQuaternions readQuats = mapper.readValue("./zeroQuatTest.json", typeRef);
```

Comment: Maybe you want to do `mapper.readValue(new File("./zeroQuatTest.json"), typeRef);`

Comment: There is no [`ObjectMapper#readValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) method that accepts a `String` as a file name. Only one that accepts a `String` as JSON content.

Comment: Docs [here](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue%28java.lang.String,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference%29).

Comment: Okay, I should have known better. Just one of those days...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have this error because jackson tries to deserialize `./zeroQuatTest.json` string instead of content of your file. Try to call

```
TypeReference<ZeroQuaternions> typeRef;
typeRef = new TypeReference<ZeroQuaternions>() {};
ZeroQuaternions readQuats = mapper.readValue(new File("./zeroQuatTest.json"), typeRef);
```